# How to know if the props already exists ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and I am trying to not overwrite files that is already existed on reactjs. But I really don't know hot to declare if the files already existed.

I've already searched the data by using get props document/search.

This is where I add it on the api

```
   creater(form) {
        debugger
        var name =  form.something.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < name; i++) {
        form.State = 1;
        if (form.Name already exist){
        form.Name=(form.something[i] + "(1)");
        this.props.poster('document/post', form);
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you storing the names? You need to store the already existing names somewhere and check if they exist before using the new ones.

Let's say you have an array storing all names. You could do something like this:

```
creater(form) {
    const names = ['Peter', 'Ben', 'Alice', 'Robert'];

    for (let i = 0; i < form.names.length; i++) { // Check each name in form and change if necessary
      if (names.indexOf(form.names[i]) > -1) { // Already exists
        form.names[i] = form.names[i]+'1';
      }
    }
    this.props.poster('document/post', form);
  }
```

Comment: thank you for answering but the names are in the database , im so confuse on retrieving it but i will use your code if i retreived the names,